# LTspice: time step too small error

Tags: ltspice

I am unable to run ltspice simulation. I have tried changing the solver to alternate, adjusting Gmin and Trtol, Changing integration method. Always get the same error.

Error message: Analysis: time step too small; initial timepoint: trouble with schmitt-instance a:u1:4

[image: ltspice circuit]

Comment: Have you consulted the experts on the LTSpice Yahoo! group?

Comment: It doesn't look like you defined any of the transient analysis parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solver probably doesn't like the open ports SDCOM and SD on U1. If they really are supposed to be open, put a 1e6Ω or 1e9Ω to ground (or whatever value they should be set to). This helps the solver find the value on those ports.

They are probably high impedance to a gate of a mosfet or something like that, if so, its either a floating net or close to it, floating nets are hard to solve for, so you need a current and a voltage so the solver can solve the net.